# Getting memory use fatal error

Tags: php, joomla

My joomla website was working fine and now is giving this error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in ...public_html/libraries/vendor/joomla/string/src/phputf8/substr_replace.php on line 20.`

I know the obvious answer is to upgrade the php.ini memory to 512M but my hosting doesn't allow it. First it was here and now

Is there other way to solve it?

Comment: It happens in all pages or some specific ones ? What is the content ? Which component is used ? It's in the administation or the public part ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have access to `php.ini`, Just create a `.htaccess` file in your joomla website root folder and add this line to it:

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Comment: Only if host allows this

Comment: @Michel why doesn't host allow you that?? Just upload it as well as other php files!!!